# JS performance: create an awful lot of elements at once

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

My web page creates a **lot** of DOM elements at once in a (batch) tight loop, depending on data fed by my Comet web server.

I tried several methods to create those elements. Basically it boils down to either (1):

```
var container = $('#selector');
for (...) container.append('<html code of the element>');
```

or (2):

```
var html = '';
for (...) html += '<html code of the element>';
$('#selector').append(html);
```

or (3):

```
var html = [];
for (...) html.push('<html code of the element>');
$('#selector').append(html.join(''));
```

Performance-wise, (1) is absolutely awful (3s per batch on a desktop computer, up to 5mn on a Galaxy Note fondleslab), and (2) and (3) are roughly equivalent (300ms on desktop, 1.5s on fondleslab). Those timings are for about 4000 elements, which is about 1/4 of what I expect in production and this is not acceptable since I should be handle this amount of data (15k elements) in under 1s, even on fondleslab.

The very fact that (2) and (3) have the same performance makes me think that I'm hitting the infamous "naively concatenating strings uselessly reallocates and copies lots of memory" problem (even though I'd expect `join()` to be smarter than that). **[edit: after looking more closely into it, it happens that I was misled about that, the problem is more on the rendering side -- thanks DanC]**

In C++ I'd just go with `std::string::reserve()` and `operator +=` to avoid the useless reallocations, but I have no idea how to do that in Javascript.

Any idea how to improve the performance further? Or at least point me to ways to identify the bottleneck (even though I'm pretty sure it's the string concatenations). I'm certainly no Javascript guru...

Thanks for reading me.

---

For what it's worth, that huge number of elements is because I'm drawing a (mostly real-time) graph using DIV's. I'm well aware of Canvas but my app has to be compatible with old browsers so unfortunately it's not an option. :(

Comment: What about using an empty jQuery object? `var container = $(); for ... container.add('..html..'); $('#selector').append(container);`.

Comment: Old browsers used Flash for this stuff.

Comment: Do you know if the bottleneck is in the string concatenation process or the time is consumed when updating the DOM and re-rendering the page with such a massive amount of elements? I would suggest timing those (string concatenation vs DOM manipulation/rendering) and discard that your problem is the time that it takes for the page to be re-rendered after the DOM is updated.

Comment: Without jQuery one would use a [`DocumentFragment`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-B63ED1A3) and add all elements to that and append the fragment to the document later. The jQuery version would probably look like Felix' code (jQuery actually uses `DocumentFragment` in its `buildFragment`).

Comment: @DanC, dammit you are probably right! It never occurred to me to time the rendering itself (the `.append()` part) but even on a small dataset it takes 500ms just by itself when the string concatenations only take about 3ms.I guess I'm hitting the limits here...

Comment: @FelixKling, I must be doing something wrong, because when I switch to your method the graph is just blank. But nevermind, as suggested by DanC I timed the various parts and it seems the rendering itself (not the Javascript code) is the problem. I'll explore ethagnawl's answer before withdrawing though, hopefully jQuery is the bottleneck?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using DOM methods, building and appending 12000 elements clocks in around 55ms on my dual-core MacBook.

```
document.getElementById('foo').addEventListener('click', function () {
    build();
}, false);

function build() {
    console.time('build');

    var fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();

    for ( var e = 0; e < 12000; e++ ) {
        var el = document.createElement('div');
        el.appendChild(document.createTextNode(e));
        fragment.appendChild(el);
    }

    document.querySelectorAll('body')[0].appendChild(fragment);

    console.timeEnd('build') 
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/K2QMh/3/)

[Resig on document.createDocumentFragment](http://ejohn.org/blog/dom-documentfragments/)

Comment: Great, your method almost halved the total time (now it only takes 700 to 900ms for 4k elements). Considering the timings I did after DanC's suggestion I suspect this is as good an answer as I'll ever get on this matter, but if you don't mind I'll still wait a bit before accepting it (who knows, someone may still pop up with the fabled silver bullet -- one can dream ;)). At any rate, this will have to do for the demo and I'll redesign the whole stuff for the prod version. Anyway, halving the response time kinda saved my hide for the demo so THANK YOU. :)

Comment: I'm glad I was able to help. Which method are you using to profile your code?

Comment: I don't know much about JS (I'm more of a C++ guy, I was amongst the ones who built the Comet server in the first place) so I'm just using `Date.now()` around the parts I want to time. I know it's not precise but it still gives me a good general idea of the timings despite the rather large variations.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a solution to the performance problem, but only a way to ensure the UI loop is free to handle other requests.

You could try something like this:

```
var container = $('#selector');
for (...) setTimeout(function() {container.append('<html code of the element>') };
```

To be slightly more performant, I would actually call `setTimeout` after every `x` iterations after building up a larger string.  And, not having tried this myself, I am not sure if the ordering of `setTimeout` calls will be preserved.  If not, then you can do something more like this:

```
var arrayOfStrings = 'each element is a batch of 100 or so elements html';
function processNext(arr, i) {
  container.append(arr[i]);
  if (i < arr.length) {
    setTimeout(function() { processNext(arr, i+1); });
  }
}
processNext(arrayOfStrings, 0);
```

Not pretty, but would ensure the UI is not locked up while the DOM is manipulated.

Comment: I understand what your suggestion is about, but unfortunately we're speaking of a *steady* stream of data here (think signal processing in the browser, because the embedded server doesn't have enough power to do it). I really need to handle that data before I can yield, if only because this is a Comet environment and if I yield before being finished then newer data *may* come in out of order because of the delayed `setTimeout`s. And then the graph will have no useful meaning. ;) Unless I am blinded by my C++ habits, yielding is a really bad thing in my situation.

Comment: I don't know your exact situation, but in theory you should be able to only set the next timeout in a current timeout so that you are assured all data is processed in order (see the second part of the solution above, which does that).

Comment: Ah yes I see now... I'll just have to use a queue because of data arriving asynchronously through Comet. Makes sense, thanks for the suggestion.